# JSON - Importing Data Using FileGetContents not showing?

Tags: php, json, youtube-api

I've been writing a little script to get monthly views for a user. When i've got the access token of the user and i var_dump the file_get_contents($url) i get a correct-json, which looks like this.

```
$views = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2014-09-29&end-date=2014-10-29&metrics=views&access_token='.$responseObj->access_token);
var_dump($views);
```

The result being:

```
{
  "kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable",
  "columnHeaders": [
    {
      "name": string,
      "dataType": string,
      "columnType": string
    },
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      2204
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'm unsure how to use JSON to import this number "2204" and echo it out. Currently i'm trying:

```
$monthlyViews = $views['rows'][0];
var_dump($monthlyViews)
```

But this isn't working and i'm not sure why. I'm getting nothing responded except an error saying:

Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /home/a1059253/public_html/oauth/callback.php on line 39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You need to parse the JSON object:

```
$json = json_decode($views);
```

PHP parses JSON into an object, not an array, so your code should be this:

```
$monthlyViews = $json->rows[0][0];
echo $monthlyViews;
```

Comment: I swear to god i love you so much. - That was actually incorrect though! =D - $json->rows[0][0]; - When using yours i got an array value returned. But i COULD NOT have done it without you.